# How to know from the client-side that a hot code push is occuring?

Tags: meteor

If I want to warn users that the application is updating (display a spinner...), I need to know when a hot code push is occurring, be it on a deployed or development app.

How to achieve this natively?
Is there any change to this specific event with the [`appcache`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/appcache) package?